# Angular application design issue

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angular project where I need to link separate part of a page with controllers so that I can update the content in different area at different times. Please refer to the screenshot attached.

[image: Content sections]

and here is my content looks like..

[image: HTML Content]

Currently I been working only on one ui-view in the main content area. But now the problem is, when I add a bank for say in my content area, I also need to display it immediately on the Navigation area as well. 
And also, Bank and other items (currently people, etc..) also comes from database based on content_type table I have.

Ob top of that, I have a notification area on top that also I need to push notification to user based on their action.

As seen in code, my current architecture is not scalable where I can update my navigation area and notification area based on changes made on content area.

I am using angular partial template to load the forms and other stuff in the content area.

Can someone please suggest how can I architect my application so that I can update all area of my application based on activity on content area?

Thanks

Comment: A proper answer to this question would be too broad and long, but in a nutshell, _services_. You put shared data that you need to update different controllers in services and then inject those services into your controllers which can act on those shared data updates.

Comment: One way I know is to use the multiple ui-view. So I think I can use something like vi-view="navigation" and ui-view="notification" to handle the notification bar at top right and navigation on the left with its own controller. and for the main content area, I can simply keep the ui-view so that I can load dynamic url into it. But I am still scratching my head to figure out, how can keep navigation and notification view loaded every time and keep changing only ui-view within a main content. stateProvider requires statte and I want these two views loadewd every time with all url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of a true answer to the question, and also I was not able to find the answer about sibling views to talk to each other, I decided to use the $boradcast and $emit to exchange the messages between different controller. I know this is not a perfect solution to my likings but I know that it will work.
This is in case someone has similar question as I do.